# Getting jqGrid to display SQL results via AccessDB plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, jqgrid, hta

I'm doing this in .hta using a MS Access .mdb file to store the data and Javascript plugin AccessDB.js (accessdb.org) to connect & query the mdb file. But I can't seem to get jqGrid to display the results of the SQL Query.

resultSet is the result of the SQL query. It seems to be showing in the getset() function outputting to the grey div box. But jqGrid isn't processing this variable for some reason where I've set the data as resultSet variable "data: resultSet,"

[image]

```
           var myDB = new ACCESSdb("Database/data.mdb", {showErrors:true});
           var SQL = "SELECT * FROM test";
           var resultSet = myDB.query(SQL);

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data:  resultSet,
            height: 250,
            colNames:['ID','name','phone'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'ID',index:'ID', width:60, sortable:false},
                {name:'name', index:'name', width:120, sortable:false},
                {name:'email', index:'phone', width:150, sorttype:"float"},
            ],
            multiselect: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            height: "100%",
            caption: "jqGrid and AccessDB"
        });
    getset() 
    });


function getset() {
var myDB = new ACCESSdb("Database/data.mdb", {showErrors:true});
var SQL = "SELECT * FROM test";
var resultSet = myDB.query(SQL)

$("#outbox").html(resultSet)
}
```

but if done manually it will show in the table.

```
var resultSet = [{"ID":"1","name":"john","email":"john@gmail.com"}]
```

[image]

Anyone got any ideas why it's not showing?

UPDATE:
it seems if I pass resultSet variable through an eval() function it works.

```
var qry = myDB.query(SQL)
var resultSet = eval(qry)
```

but i read somewhere eval() isn't recommended for injection vulnerabilities what would be a good alternative?
Although I guess it's shouldn't be a problem right? because I'm running this on a private server with no outside connections..

UPDATE2:

I got it to work with JSON.parse()!

```
var qry = myDB.query(SQL)
var resultSet = JSON.parse(qry)
```

JSON rocks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you to place the **whole** code which you use inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function () {/*here!!!*/});`. Second: you should probably change `'ID'` to `'id'` as the column name. I recommend you remove all `index` properties from `colModel`. Then you should fix syntax error: the parameter `height` are included **twice** in the code (`height: 250` and `height: "100%"`). Then I recommend you to use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start), choose "Script" tab, set breakpoint on the line `resultSet = myDB.query(SQL);` and verify the results returned in `resultSet` variable. It should be array of items.

Comment: thank you! I've got some tidying up to do. Thanks for Dev tools tip